# Convert gtable into ggplot in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Although gtable could be converted into ggplot using `ggplotify::as.ggplot`, the output is different from the origin ggplot. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
g <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
p_new <- ggplotify::as.ggplot(p)

# origin
p + theme(aspect.ratio = 2)

# changed
p_new + theme(aspect.ratio = 2)   # different figure shape from the origin one
```

How could I covert gtable into the **same** ggplot `p_new` as the origin one `p`?

Comment: This might help: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplotify/vignettes/ggplotify.html

Comment: @markus Thanks but `as.ggplot` could not do that perfectly.

Comment: `spect.ratio`? you mean `aspect.ratio`? it works for me. It is not rendered exactly the same tho. That I don't know why. for instance `aspect_ratio=10` for `p` should be `aspect_ratio=5.3` for `p_new`. Please clarify your problem.

Comment: @M-M I mean `aspect.ratio`. I just take it as an example to show that `p_new` is different from `p`.

Comment: Well you say could not be changed. It can. It's not the same tho. That's a very specific question and needs to be clarified. Please edit the question and make it clear. Otherwise, it will be closed as typo/not reproducible.

Comment: @M-M You're right. The question is how to get the same `p_new` as `p`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use  `ggplotify::as.ggplot()`:

```
library("ggplotify")
as.ggplot(q)
```